# Cocoapods update error (Errno::EHOSTUNREACH)

Tags: rubygems, updates, sudo, cocoapods

I was trying to update my cocoapods file when this error appear.

```
sudo gem update --system --verbose
  ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EHOSTUNREACH)
No route to host - sendto(2)
```

I tried searching for the solutions on the internet but to no avail.
After searching for other solutions online, it seems that this error is rare.